# MySQL - WHERE every value is IN

Tags: mysql

The following query selects all workunts where the inputs are "done" (subquery on line 7). This works fine... when there is only one input. How can I change this so that it requires *every* input to be IN that set returned by the subquery, not just one of the inputs to be present?

```
SELECT workunits.ID 
FROM workunits 
LEFT JOIN workunitInputs ON workunits.ID = workunitInputs.workunitID 
WHERE workunits.ID NOT IN (SELECT workunitID FROM jobworkunitassoc) 
AND ( 
    workunitInputs.inputID IN ( 
        SELECT workunitOutputs.outputID 
        FROM workunitOutputs 
        LEFT JOIN workunits ON workunitOutputs.workunitID = workunits.ID 
        LEFT JOIN jobworkunitassoc ON workunits.ID = jobworkunitassoc.workunitID 
        LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobworkunitassoc.jobID = jobs.ID 
        WHERE jobs.done = 1 
    ) 
    OR workunitInputs.inputID IS NULL 
) 
GROUP BY workunits.ID
```

Thanks, Istvan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query works for me, though it may not be the best solution:
http://pastebin.com/g9qBjQGU

Answer (score 0):

Change that clause to:

```
AND ( 
    workunitInputs.inputID NOT IN ( 
        SELECT workunitOutputs.outputID 
        FROM workunitOutputs 
        LEFT JOIN workunits ON workunitOutputs.workunitID = workunits.ID 
        LEFT JOIN jobworkunitassoc ON workunits.ID = jobworkunitassoc.workunitID 
        LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobworkunitassoc.jobID = jobs.ID 
        WHERE jobs.done != 1 
    )
```

This is based on the logical tautology: All X in Y === No X in !Y